# How to copy attributes from one data frame to another or to re-assign attributes to a freshly transposed data frame - R

Tags: r, attr, purrr, reshape2, tidyselect

After transposing data I'd like to re-assign attributes that are dropped. This could also be applicable to copying attributes from one data frame to another. Or copying attributes after mutates, etc., where they are dropped.

```
 library(reshape2)

 df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                  time = c(11, 22,33,44,55),
                  c  = c(1,2,3,5,5),
                  d = c(4,2,5,4,NA))

attr(df$id,"label")<- "label"
attr(df$time,"label")<- "label2"
attr(df$c,"label")<- "something here"
attr(df$d,"label")<- "count of something"
str(df)

 str(df)
 data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id  : num  1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "label"
 $ time: num  11 22 33 44 55
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "label2"
 $ c   : num  1 2 3 5 5
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ d   : num  4 2 5 4 NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
```

Cast to wide

```
dfwide<- recast(df,id~variable +time, 
            id.var = c("id","time"))
```

Usual attribute lost message:

```
   Warning message:
     attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 

 str(dfwide)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id  : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ c_11: num  1 NA NA NA NA
 $ c_22: num  NA 2 NA NA NA
 $ c_33: num  NA NA 3 NA NA
 $ c_44: num  NA NA NA 5 NA
 $ c_55: num  NA NA NA NA 5
 $ d_11: num  4 NA NA NA NA
 $ d_22: num  NA 2 NA NA NA
 $ d_33: num  NA NA 5 NA NA
 $ d_44: num  NA NA NA 4 NA
 $ d_55: num  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Using `mostattributes` one can copy attributes between dataframes, but for iterations over many column names I can't figure out or think about how to map this efficiently in a different way save one by one.

```
 mostattributes(dfwide$c_11)<-attributes(df$c)
 mostattributes(dfwide$c_22)<-attributes(df$c)
 > str(dfwide)
 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  11 variables:
  $ id  : num  1 2 3 4 5
  $ c_11: num  1 NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
  $ c_22: num  NA 2 NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
  $ c_33: num  NA NA 3 NA NA
```

I was trying to automate it but failed (all c's should have same labels and d's have same labels):

```
#extract arguments
dlist<-enframe(names(df))%>%
   slice(-1,-2)%>%
   pull(., value)
 dlist

 dlistw<-enframe(names(dfwide))%>%
  slice(-1)%>%
  pull(., value)
 dlistw

#function
mostatt<- function(var1, var2) {
  mostattributes(dfwide[[var1]])<<-attributes(df[[var2]])
}

mapply(mostatt,dlistw,dlist)
str(dfwide)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id  : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ c_11: num  1 NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ c_22: num  NA 2 NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
 $ c_33: num  NA NA 3 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ c_44: num  NA NA NA 5 NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
 $ c_55: num  NA NA NA NA 5
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ d_11: num  4 NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
 $ d_22: num  NA 2 NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ d_33: num  NA NA 5 NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
 $ d_44: num  NA NA NA 4 NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "something here"
 $ d_55: num  NA NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "count of something"
```

I think using `tidyselect` `starts_with` might be worth a try but not sure how to incorporate it. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option:

```
for(i in (setdiff(colnames(df), "id"))){
  for(x in colnames(dfwide)[(grepl(i, colnames(dfwide)))])
      mostattributes(dfwide[[x]]) <- attributes(df[[i]])
}
mostattributes(dfwide$id) <- attributes(df$id)
```

Because `d` is contained in `id` I need to rewrite `id` at the end. 
If you change `d` for `e` is even simplier:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 time = c(11, 22,33,44,55),
                 c  = c(1,2,3,5,5),
                 e = c(4,2,5,4,NA))


attr(df$id,"label")<- "label"
attr(df$time,"label")<- "label2"
attr(df$c,"label")<- "something here"
attr(df$e,"label")<- "count of something"
str(df)

dfwide<- recast(df,id~variable +time, 
                id.var = c("id","time"))

for(i in (colnames(df))){
  for(x in colnames(dfwide)[(grepl(i, colnames(dfwide)))])
    mostattributes(dfwide[[x]]) <- attributes(df[[i]])
}
```

Comment: That's a good option. Thank you for sharing. I didn't realize one could grep/grepl like that. I wonder if there is a way to add a regex carat ^ to the statement to signify the start position of the pattern. I'll play around with it. But as it is this solution works for me because the colnames in the dataframes I have are much longer and the grepl will work on those strings instead of a single character. Thank you again!